# Trace of point begin circle under certain condition

Tags: geometry

Let $P$ be a point on a circle $(x-2)^2 + (y-2)^2 = 4$. Now let $Q$ be a point on the same line with $O$, the origin, $P$, and also on the first quadrant.
If $Q$ satisfies $\overline{OP}\times\overline{OQ}=6$, the trace of $Q$ is a circle, $(x-3)^2 + (y-3)^2 = 9$.

Is there a generalized theorem or an easy explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inverting in the circle $x^2+y^2=6$ (see [inversive geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry) on Wikipedia).  The inverse of a circleline is a circleline.  Since your starting circle doesn't pass through the origin, it ends up as a circle.